# Why my header cannot download a file?

Tags: php, download, header

I want to get information and download it through a file. But it just open a new window and show the information in it.

```
$filename = $this->input->cookie('merchant_id');
$timestamp = date("YmdHis",time());
$filename .= $timestamp.'.'.$fileType;

$title = mb_convert_encoding($title,'gbk','utf-8');

header('Content-type: application/octet-stream');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $filename);
echo $title;

$ret = $this->download_model->QueryList($Req, $Resp);
$content = $this->GetDownLoadContentNew($ret['bill_list'], $fileType);
echo $content;
```

The GetDownLoadContentNew function just format the content.
So, why it cannot download?

Comment: I may be misunderstanding but is it just a text file? Browsers can display that so you can probably just hit "Ctrl+S" to save the file in your browser.

Comment: @varlogtim : i want to click a button on the page and download a file, but now it open a new window displaying the infomation when i click the button. So that's the problem.

Comment: I may be wrong, but in my experience, that sometimes depends on the browser. For example, if you try downloading a PDF, firefox will open it in it's own PDF viewer from where you can save it, but safari will directly let you download the file. I think the similar thing goes with your case too. Try your code in different browsers.

Comment: @SajibAcharya :I tried in firefox, chrom and IE, but they're all the same

Comment: @Will what is the file type that you are trying to download?

Comment: @SajibAcharya txt or csv. The two type both have the problem